# What kind of random variable describes the angle between a line and a plane?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In 2D, the angle between a randomly oriented line and X-axis can be described by the uniform random variable X~Uniform(0,Pi). What kind of random variable can describe the angle between a randomly oriented line in a 3D space and the XY plane? My intuition tells me that it is not a uniform random variable. But I do not know how to derive the right random variable.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why wouldn't you do the exact same thing? A line and a plane in 3D have an angle that you can define, just as two lines in 2D do.

Comment: The intuition that it is not uniformly random is because, through any given point, only one perpendicular line passes but infinitely many parallel ones.
This might help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for here, but if we equate choosing a direction for the line and choosing a uniformly random point on the unit sphere, then we can make progress.

We can then limit ourselves to just a unit hemisphere, because we have symmetry between the two opposing sides of the plane. Now we just need to figure out what portion of the unit hemisphere lies below/above a certain angle $\phi$. We can do this via integration in spherical coordinates to get

$$P(x < \phi_0) =k\int_0^{\phi_0}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\phi\ d\theta\ d\phi = k\int_0^{\phi_0} 2\pi\sin\phi\ d\phi = k\cdot2\pi(1-\cos\phi_0)$$
I added the factor $k$ in to normalize the distribution, and looking at the value when $\phi_0=1$, we see $k=\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Thus, we have
$$P(x < \phi_0) = 1-\cos(\phi_0)$$
And if you wanted to write this as a continuous PDF, you could use the function
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}P(x < \phi_0) =\sin(\phi_0)$$
Finally remember the domain is only $[0,\pi/2]$. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Issac. Thank you very much for your response. It was helpful. My apologizes for responding late.